# How to Read the Drop Down value using Javascript in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to know how to read the DropDown list value from the JSP. Below is the code of my JSP.

```
   <fieldset>
   <s:form theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="uploadDocument" method="POST" action="?">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td wrap>Select The Type of Letter to Upload:</td><td><s:select id="letters" list="letterList" name="ListofLetters" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--Select The Letter Type--"/></td>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap ><s:file name="userFile" label="userFile" size="25" id="upload" /></td>
    <td  class="button-blue"><s:submit action="Upload" value="Attach File" onclick=" return validateFile()"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </s:form>
    </fieldset>
```

where the list is populated dynamically from the Database.I wanted to know how to get the Dropdownlist value not the key.
Because when i used

```
document.getElementById('letters').value
```

It returns me the keyvalue like "0,1,2 etc" how can i get the value associated with the individual key so i can perform the proper check.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: By "value" you mean the selected option's text, I presume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get the currently selected option's text:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('letters');
var selText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3M9qV/)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('letters').value; // returns the value ie 1 / 2 / 3 etc

var dropdown=document.getElementById('letters');
dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text; // returns the text
```

Hope this helps.